# sending JSON via AJAX to RESTful Service (jersey) returns null values

Tags: ajax, json, rest, null, jersey

sorry for asking again but i cant find the solution for my problem - neither here, nor anywhere else. I have a RESTful server using jersey who should consume a JSON via ajax from the client....but it returns a null value. Why??

REST:

```
@POST
@Path("/addPoint")
@Consumes({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
@Produces({ MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON })
public WayPoint addPoint(@QueryParam("coordinate")String coordinate, @QueryParam("RouteId")Long RouteId) {
    WayPoint waypoint = new WayPoint();
    waypoint.setCoordinate(coordinate);
    waypoint.setRouteId(RouteId);
    System.out.println(waypoint);
    return getEntityManager().merge(waypoint);  
}
```

the object:

```
@Entity
@XmlRootElement
public class WayPoint {

@Id
@Column(nullable = false)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.TABLE)
private Long id;

private String coordinate;

private Long RouteId;

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getCoordinate() {
    return coordinate;
}

public void setCoordinate(String coordinate) {
    this.coordinate = coordinate;
}

public Long getRouteId() {
    return RouteId;
}

public void setRouteId(Long routeId) {
    this.RouteId = routeId;
}

}
```

and the AJAX call:

```
this.AddPoint = function(coords, routeid){
    var test = JSON.stringify({ coordinate: coords, RouteId: routeid });
    console.log(test);
    $.ajax({ 
        url: thePath,
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify({ coordinate: coords, RouteId: routeid }),
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function(response) {
            alert("new point added!");
            console.log(response);
        },
        error:function(res){
            alert("Cannot save point! " + res.statusText);
        }
    }); 
};
```

i don't get it...coordinate and RouteId are "null" when i try to extract them that way (via @queryParam)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I understand, you can only use `@QueryParam` for GET requests.

For POSTs you can put the object you want to populate as the method parameter and Jersey will instantiate it automatically for you.

I think you just have to ensure that the object to instantiate has the appropriate getters and setters.

A GET example:

```
   @GET
   @Path("logout")
   @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
   public Response logout(@NotNull @QueryParam("user_id") int userId, 
                          @NotNull @QueryParam("token") String token) {
```

A POST example:

```
  @POST
  @Path("register")
  @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
  public Response register(RegisterUserParams registerUserParams) {
```

Comment: when i change the ajax call and the annotaion into GET, the parameters are still null - how can i get the parameters via POST? i think i do rly stupid atm....

Comment: You shouldn't be doing `JSON.stringify` for the `data` parameter of your ajax call. Just leave it as the JSON object.